# Ordering plotly bars in a grouped-split bar chart

Tags: r, split, plotly, bar-chart

I have a `data.frame` with counts for several `group`s that are assigned to several `loci` from two `age`s:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("G1",2),rep("G2",2),rep("G3",2)),
                 locus = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2)),
                 age = rep(c("2m","24m"),3),
                 n = as.integer(runif(6,10,100)),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to plot these data in a bar chart using `plotly` in `R`, where the x-axis is `group`, the bars are split by `age`, and colored by the combination of `locus` and `age`.

I set `group`, `locus`, and `age` as `factor`s to give them the order I want them to folow in the figure:

```
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("G1","G2","G3"))
df$locus <- factor(df$locus, levels = c("A","B"))
df$age <- factor(df$age,levels = c("2m","24m"))
```

Now I'm creating a `data.frame` with the specific colors I'd like each of the `locus`-`age` combination to have:

```
library(dplyr)
color.df <- data.frame(locus = c("A","A","B","B"), age = rep(c("2m","24m"),2), color = c("#66C2A5","#488A75","#FC8D62","#B46446"),stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(locus_age=paste0(locus,"_",age))
color.df$locus <- factor(color.df$locus, levels=c("A","B"))
color.df$age <- factor(color.df$age, levels=c("2m","24m"))
color.df$locus_age <- factor(color.df$locus_age,levels=color.df$locus_age)
```

Then joining `df` with `color.df`:

```
df <- dplyr::left_join(df,color.df)
```

And finally plotting:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = df$group, y = df$n, split = df$age, text = df$n, type = 'bar', color = df$locus_age, colors = color.df$color, showlegend = T,
                      textposition = "inside", textfont = list(size=12,color='black')) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="N"))
```

Which gives:
[image]

My questions are:

1. Although I defined the `df$age` order to be `c("2m","24m")` the `"24m"` age appears before the `"2m"` age, as if the `split` argument in the `plot_ly` function is ignoring this order. Any idea how to fix this?
2. Looks like the legend is labelling both `age` and the `locus_age`. Any idea how to make it only label by `locus_age`?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, it seems to me that the `split` argument is causing the issues.

I have also streamlined the code so that there is a continuous pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
data.frame(locus = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
           age = rep(c("2m", "24m"), 2),
           color = c("#66C2A5", "#488A75", "#FC8D62", "#B46446"),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(locus_age = paste0(locus, "_", age)) %>%
  mutate(locus = factor(locus, levels = c("A", "B"))) %>%
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels = c("2m", "24m"))) %>%
  mutate(locus_age = forcats::fct_inorder(locus_age)) %>% 
  left_join(df, .) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~group, y = ~n, 
          # split = ~age,
          text = ~n, type = 'bar', 
          color = ~locus_age, colors = ~color, showlegend = TRUE,
          textposition = "inside", textfont = list(size = 12, color = 'black')) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "N"))
```

[image]

Now, the factor levels seem to be in the expected order and the legend shows only `locus_age`.

#### Caveat

Dealing with factors can become tricky sometimes as factor levels are not always created in the expected order.

If we create a character vector in the expected order

```
x <- outer(c("A", "B"), c("2m", "24m"), paste, sep = "_") %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.vector()
 x
```

> ```
> [1] "A_2m"  "A_24m" "B_2m"  "B_24m"
> ```

base R's

```
factor(x)
```

(without specifying factor levels explicitely)

creates a factor whose levels are sorted in the current locale by default:

> ```
> [1] A_2m  A_24m B_2m  B_24m
> Levels: A_24m A_2m B_24m B_2m
> ```

Alternatively,

```
forcats::as_factor(x)
```

creates factor levels in order of appearance (if x is character)

> ```
> [1] A_2m  A_24m B_2m  B_24m
> Levels: A_2m A_24m B_2m B_24m
> ```

or even more explicitely

```
forcats::fct_inorder(x)
```